# Creating a view with a dynamic link from taxonomy term

Tags: views, blocks, navigation

Trying to create a view block with a list of five links

- Event Details (dynamic)
- Cause (dyanmic)
- Sponsors (statis)
- Volunteer (static)
- Register (static)

Dynamic url will look like this:

/events/golf-tournament/[year]/[taxonomy-term]/event-details

/events/golf-tournament/[year]/[taxonomy-term]/cause

I am not able to format the taxonomy term to use it in the url

[image: Creating a view with a dynamic link from taxonomy term]

Taxonomy term prints as: The William Dennis Memorial Golf Tournament (with capitals and spaces)

View looks like this: 
[image: Each field is a rewrite to produce a link - that is except Year and Golf Tournament, which are the tokens to be replaced in the url]

** Solution **
*  Not sure if this is the 'right' way *

Added contextual filter for: Content: has taxonomy term ID

But it doesn't appear to use the taxonomy term....so really I providing a value from the url

[image: Raw value from URL]

Then I messed around with tokens, first trying [token_taxonomy_term] <--- not actual token; %1 and !1 <---- all of these exist in the available Replacement Patterns

[image: Replacement Patterns]

Here is the rewrite I used to rewrite the url for 'cause'

Cause

Comment: What happens if you try to use one of the validation filters offered by the contextual link to replace spaces with dashes?

Comment: When I add contextual filters all contents of the view disappear.

Comment: What contextual filters are you adding and how are they configured?

Comment: *configuration added to issue*

Comment: What happens if you enter the term in the preview field on the view instead of the default field on the contextual filter? Also, which type of contextual filter is this?

Comment: Type == Content: Has taxonomy term ID

Comment: I'm not able to get anything to work when I enter the contextual filter in the preview

Answer (score 0):

In the contextual filters you may have to add the Context: Has taxonomy term ID filter.  You can set the Specify validation criteria settings.  The validator option is usually Taxonomy Term, but other validator options are available. Make sure to choose Term Name converted to Term ID, as this is what is needed to be passed for to the url.  Also check the Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values checkbox underneath.
Choose your action to take if the filter value does not validate dropdown.